# Using Android ProgressDialog with AsyncTask and odd Activity Lifecycle

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I couldn't think of a way to form my title to make my issue obvious, so here goes:

I'm a little over my head with diving into AsyncTask for the first time. I currently have an app that simply sends a tweet. To do this it must kick out to a WebView for Twitter authorization, which comes back to onNewIntent().

What I'm trying to do is throw up a simple Spinner ProgressDialog while it's connecting to the site/performing the AccessToken work, and then again while it's sending the tweet. I've only just discovered that I will need a new thread for the progress bar. Or rather, that I should be doing my "time-intensive work" in it's own separate thread to make using a ProgressDialog viable. My question is this: How can I have my progress spinner in the foreground while my authorization code works in the background, and eventually opens the WebView and comes back, and ultimately starts everything over at onResume()?

I'm sure I'm probably not doing everything else in the most proper fashion. I'm new to Android, but not to Java. I've put in my create- and dismissDialog(int) calls about where they should be, procedurally. As-is, everything otherwise works the way it should, but obviously my dialogs are simply not able show themselves.

I'm thinking I should basically put my entire authorize() and tweet() methods into their own AsyncTask. I'm just not sure how to go about that, especially since authorize() (or more specifically, loginToTwitter()) needs to end up saving the data it gets from the browser to shared preferences after it comes back to onNewIntent().

Thanks for any insights,
== Matt

```java
public class IntegrateTwitter extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(); 
        mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

        if(authorize()) {
            tweet();
            returnToMM();
        }
    }

    private boolean authorize() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Authorizing...");   
        showDialog(PD_AUTHORIZING);
        boolean result = false;

        if(responseExistsAndValid()) {
            saveResponseToAccessToken();
        }

        if(isAuthorized()) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Prefs have AccessToken, grabbing it...");
            if(getAccessTokenFromPrefs()) {
                Toast.makeText(IntegrateTwitter.this, "Authorized.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                result = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Prefs don't have AccessToken.");

            if(!responseStringExists()) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "No response exists either, starting Twitter login process...");
                Toast.makeText(IntegrateTwitter.this, "Authorizing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Here is where it kicks out to the browser for authentication
                loginToTwitter();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(IntegrateTwitter.this, "Authorization failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Response exists, so it must have failed once already, skipping Twitter login process.");
                returnToMM();
            }
        }

        deleteResponseFromPrefs();

        dismissDialog(PD_AUTHORIZING);
        return result;
    }

    private void tweet() {
        showDialog(PD_TWEETING);

        try {
            Date testDate = new Date();
            String testDateString  = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd @ hh:mm:ss", testDate.getTime()).toString();
            mTwitter.updateStatus(testDateString + " Test Tweet");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tweet successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (TwitterException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tweet error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }

        dismissDialog(PD_TWEETING);
    }

    // A bunch of support methods
    // ...  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.....

I think you know that if we are **not using AsyncTask**, we can always use **Thread along with Handler, to Post the work done on Non-UI thread to UI thread**.

**AsyncTask** is provided by android to **sync** the UI and Non-UI work seamlessly.

I got this example by searching on Google, **but changed it the way you wanted it to be.**

**Here it will Count till 50... and until it does it will keep displaying the ProgressDialog.
Please see the log while the program is executing to see the count increasing till 50.**

```
public class AsyncTaskExampleActivity extends Activity 
{
        protected TextView _percentField;
        protected Button _cancelButton;
        protected InitTask _initTask;
        ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        _percentField = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.percent_field );
        _cancelButton = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.cancel_button );
        _cancelButton.setOnClickListener( new CancelButtonListener() );

        _initTask = new InitTask();


         pd = ProgressDialog.show(AsyncTaskExampleActivity.this, "Loading", "Please Wait");


        _initTask.execute( this );
    }

    protected class CancelButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener 
    {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        _initTask.cancel(true);
                }
    }

    /**
     * sub-class of AsyncTask
     */
    protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String>
    {
        // -- run intensive processes here
        // -- notice that the datatype of the first param in the class definition matches the param passed to this method 
        // -- and that the datatype of the last param in the class definition matches the return type of this method
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground( Context... params ) 
                {
                        //-- on every iteration
                        //-- runs a while loop that causes the thread to sleep for 50 milliseconds 
                        //-- publishes the progress - calls the onProgressUpdate handler defined below
                        //-- and increments the counter variable i by one
                        int i = 0;
                        while( i <= 50 ) 
                        {
                                try{
                                        Thread.sleep( 50 );
                                        publishProgress( i );
                                        i++;
                                } catch( Exception e ){
                                        Log.i("makemachine", e.getMessage() );
                                }
                        }
                        pd.dismiss(); 
                        return "COMPLETE!";
                }

                // -- gets called just before thread begins
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onPreExecute()" );

                        super.onPreExecute();

                }

                // -- called from the publish progress 
                // -- notice that the datatype of the second param gets passed to this method
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
                {
                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onProgressUpdate(): " +  String.valueOf( values[0] ) );
                        _percentField.setText( ( values[0] * 2 ) + "%");
                        _percentField.setTextSize( values[0] );
                }

                // -- called if the cancel button is pressed
                @Override
                protected void onCancelled()
                {
                        super.onCancelled();
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onCancelled()" );
                        _percentField.setText( "Cancelled!" );
                        _percentField.setTextColor( 0xFFFF0000 );
                }

                // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
                // -- notice that the third param gets passed to this method
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute( String result ) 
                {

                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onPostExecute(): " + result );
                        _percentField.setText( result );
                        _percentField.setTextColor( 0xFF69adea );
                        _cancelButton.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've since learned a little bit about AsyncTasks and now realize how to effectively use onPre- and onPostExexcute. My problem now is more that I have to deal with race conditions and Activity lifecycle while using the AsycTask, but my further problems have kind of grown outside the scope of this question, so I'll marked it as answered. What I've actually done is started implementing this AsyncTaskManager class with listeners for completed tasks: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162201/Painless-AsyncTask-and-ProgressDialog-Usage).